# How to replace a String with a new value that matches a pattern?

Tags: java, regex, xml

The application receives a XML message (input) something like:

```
String input = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message>
   <property name="name1" value="value1" type="A"/>
   <property name="name2" value="valu%@1" type="B"/>
   <property name="name3" value="my value=\"test\"" type="B"/>
</message>";
```

I need to parse this XML (String) and make sure all the values are XML sanitized. I use Apache's StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml() to make sure all special characters are encoded.

```
String regex = "(?<=value=\")([^\"]+).*?(?=\" type=\")";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile (regex);
```

And

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher (input);
while (matcher.find()) {
  String oldValue = m.group(1);
  String newValue = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(oldValue);
  ??
}
```

I only want each value to be sanitized and replaced individually not just any occurrence of it. Either it does not work or I get IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference while using replaceAll or replaceFirst.

What would be most efficient way to do it?

Thanks-

Comment: Where are you using `replaceAll()` or `replaceFirst()`?

Comment: @jonathan - Inside the while loop after newValue.

Comment: I changed it to the following and it works: while (matcher.find()) {
                    String oldName = matcher.group();
                    String newName = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(oldName);
                    input = input.replace(oldName, newName);
                }

Comment: Is the problem resolved now?